# Смещение позиции списка при поиске

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-on-click

Написал поиск с трудом для `RecycleView` но проблема в том что раньше я брал позицию элемента списка и переходил по ссылке. Теперь же при поиске высвечивается найденные элемент списка и переходит не по том который задан а по  первом потому что этот элемент списка переместился с Например 20 места на 1. Как закрепить элемент списка за ссылкой перехода на другое `Activity`
***Очень большая просьба НЕ ПРЕДЛАГАЙТЕ ПЕРЕВОДИТЬ КРАТКИЙ СПИСОК В БАЗУ ДАННЫХ `sqLite`  ИЛИ В `json` ***

КОД активити

```
public class Material extends BaseActivity implements DialogUtilities.OnCompleteListener, BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{

    ArrayList<String> mNames;
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    EditText editText;
    RecyclerView recyclerv_view;
    private RecycleViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.materials);


        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        initImageBitmaps();

    }
    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<String> filteredNames = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s : mNames) {
            if (s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredNames.add(s);
            }
        }
        adapter.filterList(filteredNames);
    }

   private void initImageBitmaps(){
        mNames = new ArrayList<>();
        //0
        mImageUrls.add("https://u.livelib.ru/reader/vwvw2008/o/fmhclhxy/o-o.jpeg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.base_krok));
        //1
        mImageUrls.add("https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/01/17/589833/ae71f6d11c0ad38688daa0e17dd9b8be.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.chemistry));
        //2
        mImageUrls.add("https://ukrinnovate.com/upload/website-science-or-innovation-article-image-201803191200.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.hisology));
        //3
        mImageUrls.add("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36spQsZ5pqQ/maxresdefault.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.hygiena));
        //4
        mImageUrls.add("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/kletki_mikrobiologiya_struktura_113059_1920x1080.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.micro));
        //5
        mImageUrls.add("https://dekart-school.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/biologiya-oge.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.biology));
        //7
        mImageUrls.add("https://mbbs.doctors.ind.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/anatomy.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.anatomy));
        //8
        mImageUrls.add("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-ME8kezZ0Wc/maxresdefault.jpg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.physiology));

        initRecyclerView();
}
    private void initRecyclerView(){
        recyclerv_view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
        adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
        recyclerv_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerv_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
```

Код Адаптера

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleViewAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImageNames, ArrayList<String> mImages) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.material, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.image1);

        holder.image_name.setText(mImageNames.get(position));

        holder.parent_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), BaseKrok.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Chemistry.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Histology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Hygiene.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Microbiology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Biology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Anatomy.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Physiology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), OperSurgery.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }


    public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filteredList) {
        mImageNames = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image1;
        TextView image_name;
        CardView parent_layout;
        LinearLayout lin;
        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            image_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parent_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            lin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lin);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно добавить в pojo что то типа implements Serializeble, но это не точно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переходите на нужное активити не по позиции, а по имени предмета (пример для двух элементов), так же вызов активити (повторяющееся действие) лучше вынести за пределы свитча.

**UPD** Еще, чтобы работал свитч, вам нужно изменить тип коллекции `mImageNames` с `String` на `Integer`, так как он хранит целые числа (идентификаторы строк в ресурсах), а не сами строки (соответственно изменить тип нужно и в других связанных с этой коллекцией местах).

```
private ArrayList<Integer> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();

holder.parent_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (mImageNames.get(position)){
                case R.string.base_krok:
                    intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), BaseKrok.class);
                    break;
                case R.string.chemistry:
                    intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Chemistry.class);
                    break;
            }
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
}
```

Comment: Умно придумано, но к сожалению не работает(

Comment: Пишет Incompatible types все решается если сделать так `case  "R.string.base_krok" ` но я ведь достаю строку с ресурсов

Comment: Intent intent = null; ещё это нужно добавить.

Comment: @VladBulan вам нужно изменить тип коллекции, добавил в ответ